# What possible cfthread statuses are there?

Tags: coldfusion

I am creating an app that needs to know the current status of dynamically named threads..

But since i was unable to get the value as a variable, i must check for each possible status, in my cfc to return some value indicating the current status...

Been digging for good articles on this....like http://cfsearching.blogspot.com/2008/01/using-runtimeexec-mencoder-and-cfthread.html but the documentation is rather sparse...

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=threads_5.html):

```
NOT_STARTED
RUNNNG
TERMINATED
COMPLETED
WAITING
```

Comment: thank you, and how can i check that, if i am using a dynamic name? I am struggling to get the data, because i have to evaluate(cfthread.my_name.status)...

Comment: Not sure if this is what you mean, but try `cfthread[name_variable].status`?

Comment: Okay ty, but i am grabbing the threadname from a query, so it's like cfthread[#queryname.thread_name#].status or is that the wrong syntax?

Comment: No hashes required - just cfthread[queryname.thread_name].status (assuming you're inside a suitable cfloop of course).